# Map my router's public IP to one of my PC's in the wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Suppose I have a public IP. If I enter that IP into any PC connected to the internet, it opens my Router's Admin panel and asks for it's username and password, fair enough.

But is that possible instead of opening the admin panel, it routes to one of the PC's that is connected to the router via it's Wifi network?

My router's model is TP-Link WR340G.

I have made my PC have a reserved IP from my router, it always is assigned the same IP via the router when it connects to the Wifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you should disable the "Remote management" feature, unless you really want to be able to access your router's administration remotely.  Normally, this should be disabled.  You can do that on your router by going to Under "Security" and selecting "Remote Management"

Now, to forward traffic to your PC selecting "Forwarding" and then "Virtual Servers".  Add a new service using port 80, and the IP of your PC.

Comment: Thanks. Is that safe if I keep the remote management in some other port? Because there seems to be no disabling option. It worked but can you explain why only the port 80 is usable for this case? Thanks for your answer though, tremendous help :)

Comment: As far as the remote management goes, I'd tell it to listen on the router's LAN IP only (something like 192.168.1.1).  Port 80 is the default HTTP port, so that is the port your browser automatically tries to connect to.

Comment: I've tried with the other ports (Random ones such as 9999, 1234 etc) but none worked even if I specifically called them like <my-ip>:1234. The connection always failed. That's what's confusing me the most.